# Update a field of an associate table using the magic method of Sequelize/Node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I have i table called Orders and another table called Cupons, this tables has a association many to one, Ordes has many cupons, and cupons belongs to order, i need to update the status of my cupom when i associate the cupons to a order, i tried this way but doesn't work

`````
await item.addCupons(cupom.id, { // the item is the order created 
            through: {
                afiliado_id: afiliadoId, // and update the afiliado id 
                status: 'validado' // update de status of cupon to 'validado'
            }
        })
    ````
`````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only `create` a parent and child records using one method but not to `update` both. You need to explicitly call `update` for `Order` item:

```js
await Cupon.update({
  afiliado_id: afiliadoId,
  status: 'validado'
}, {
 where: {
   id: cupom.id
 }
})
await item.addCupons(cupom.id)
```

`through` option is applicable for many-to-many relationships only.

Comment: Thank you, this is gonna help me a lot.